# PHP: require doesn' work

Tags: php

My directory root:

```
src/
   database.php
   Contact-Controller/
        contact.php
```

contact.php (None of these requires work):

```
require (__DIR__  . '/src/database.php');
require 'src/database.php';
require './src/database.php';
```

But on a other file

Directory:

```
src/
   Search-Controller/
        offer-count.php
```

On "offer-count.php" is `require 'src/database.php` working with no Error 500.

I don't understand, why on some files work `require 'src/database.php` and on other files not. Where is the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `..` to go to the parent directory of the current directory. So the correct way would be like this:

```
require '../database.php';
```

Comment: Please, include som explanation of the magic constant `__DIR__`. Thank you. He will understand why his code was not working and will not make the same mistake again.